# How do I install my NETGEAR N600 Dual Band USB Adapter WNDA3100

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, wireless, raspbian-wheezy

On the plastic around the USB wireless device it says that I should install the driver first.

So can I just plug it in and see what happens or should I install the driver first?

Second, where can I find the driver for my NETGEAR WNDA3100?

I am using: Raspbian “wheezy” for the OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally manufacturers do not distribute linux drivers, and they must be reverse engineered by someone else.  Typically the manufacturers are very unhelpful in this regard, and so it is not possible to maintain a driver for every possible device.

But there are drivers for most common things.  Just not all.

If you are buying stuff to use with the pi, the [elinux rpi verified peripherals page](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals) is a good thing to consult.  Unfortunately, the WDNA3100 is listed under the "Problem USB Wifi Adapters", so maybe you should leave the plastic on ;)

Comment: What do you recommend I get?

Comment: @Jean-NicolasBoulayDesjardins i've used both the [Edimax EW-7811Un](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B003MTTJOY/ref=pd_sim_e_2) and the [Linksys WUSB54GC](http://www.amazon.com/Cisco-Linksys-Refurbished-Wireless-G-Compact-USB/dp/B002F7EEZI) successfully with Raspbian

Comment: My office is in a basement and the router is in the frist floor. Is the Edimax EW-7811Un powerful enough to go trough the sealing and a wall?

Comment: I've got a wee lil TP-Link WN725N which works (very well) when plugged directly into the pi but not, for some reason, from an external hub.  There are at least two other people on that page who claim it works fine for them, so if you see one around and can't find the edimax it's probably worth it (I think they are a "cheap and plentiful" item, $10-15).  WRT to going to a router in the basement, I think the *router* is more the limiting factor.