# WNDA3100 Drivers

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-2

I have scoured the internet looking for drivers for the WNDA3100 wifi dongle. I am using Raspbian Jessie. My RPi is the 2 B+ model. I cannot find the drivers anywhere. Wherever I look, I am told to use Windows to install the drivers, and move them to the Raspbian.

I will be happy to provide more information when asked.

Answer (score 1):

> Wherever I look, I am told to use Windows to install the drivers, and move them to the Raspbian.

This is nonsense, and I'm not sure why anyone would tell you to do this. Drivers must be written for their respective operating systems.

According to Netgear's [website](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-adapters/WNDA3100.aspx#tab-techspecs), there is no Linux support for that particular Wifi Dongle. If it doesn't work by simply plugging it in, you'll need to purchase a different model.

Comment: I have found a website with the link to the driver, but I can not find it again despite my hours of searching.

Comment: @TylerRichardson: For an **ARM linux** driver? I find that doubtful...

Answer (score 1):

As Jacobm01 says in his [answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44213/wnda3100-drivers#answer-44214), there is not official driver supplied for that particular Wi-Fi device, for the Pi, when the Pi is running Raspbian.

The WNDA3100 might work, if you were to install Windows 10 IoT - not that I am recommending that. Having said that, as Jacobm01 points out in his [comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/44213/wnda3100-drivers#comment-64845), the Windows 10 IoT driver would still require to have been compiled for ARM, en lieu of x86, so, until those drivers become available, the WNDA3100 would still not work.

Take a look at the thread, [No WiFi Adapters found - Netgear WNDA3100](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=28055), in particular:

> See the warning here for that device (This applies to version 2):
>
> http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals
>
> You will have to search around for a driver, as it does not exist with the Linux operating system as shipped.

As that answer suggests, you are best off using the WNDA3100 on some other device, and instead looking for a peripheral that is verified to work with the Pi, by checking the list at [RPi VerifiedPeripherals](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals).

See also: [How do I install my NETGEAR N600 Dual Band USB Adapter WNDA3100](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/5349/how-do-i-install-my-netgear-n600-dual-band-usb-adapter-wnda3100)

#### Update

However, if you use Ubuntu, instead of Raspbian, then there is a chance that you could use `ndiswrapper`, see the answer to this question: [WNDA3100 wireless adapter has stopped working under Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/352809/wnda3100-wireless-adapter-has-stopped-working-under-ubuntu-12-04). Also, as Ubuntu and Raspbian share the same Debian base, this method could still be applicable in your case. I have not tried this though. Maybe someone else could elaborate?

Comment: Since the only provided drivers are for `x86` standard Windows editions, I wouldn't assume that it would work for Win IOT.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Good point. Thanks I'll update my answer. However, meanwhile, I have found this: [WNDA3100 wireless adapter has stopped working under Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/352809/wnda3100-wireless-adapter-has-stopped-working-under-ubuntu-12-04), so it could be possible to use `ndiswrapper`.